# Реализация логирования в проекте MAUI

Tags: логирование, maui, nlog

Есть небольшой проект MAUI.

Пытаюсь реализовать введение журнала логов. Необходимо, чтобы по нажатию кнопки, логи можно было сохранить в отдельный файл на устройстве.

Знаю про Nlog и MetroLog, но не могу разобраться в их реализации.

Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать логирование?

Comment: See MetroLog: https://github.com/roubachof/MetroLog

Comment: See NLog: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog